# Is there an interface for bootstrap sampling in rattle in R?

Tags: machine-learning, r, rattle

I am using rattle in R for predictive models and am trying to see whether there is a difference in different sampling methods. The split function at the start of rattle for splitting into training and testing (optional validation) I take it is split validation. Is there a way to do bootstrap validation and cross validation directly in rattle?